# Reading in a CSV file horizontallty and ignoring new line characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Okay so this is a bit of a weird question but here goes.
I have been reading in a csv file that looks like this:

```
Name,John,Susan,
Date,3/14/2019,3/14/2019
Job,Doctor,Cashier
```

The first string in every row is the key that I want to add into a dictionary so it looks like this:

```
{"Name": ["John", "Susan"], "Date": ["3/14/2019, "3/14/2019"], "Job": ["Doctor", "Cashier"]}
```

I have been doing this all without the use of CSV reader or pandas due to the horizontal aspect of the data and it all works fine. The problem is when I run into a csv file that looks like this:

```
Name,John,Susan,
Date,"3
/14/
2019",3/14/2019
Job,Doctor,Cashier
```

When reading in the data, it should come out to "3\n/14/\n2019", however I am reading in the file line by line in order to do it without CSV eader or pandas so I have this super weird algorithm that works like 80% of the time to catch things like this. Does anyone have a solution to this? I can supply more info if needed and am open to using CSV reader or pandas if it is possible that way. Thank you!

Comment: I had no problem with csv reader, import csv

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
 csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
 for row in csv_reader:
  print(row) why cant you use it?

Comment: You miss a string literal here: ["3/14/2019, "3/14/2019"]. Does that fix your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV reader can handle your csv with the extra newlines.

data.csv

```
Name,John,Susan,
Date,"3
/14/
2019",3/14/2019
Job,Doctor,Cashier
```

Code

```
import csv
myDict = {}
with open("data.csv") as file:
    for line in csv.reader(file):
        myDict[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

```
print(myDict)
{'Name': ['John', 'Susan', ''], 'Date': ['3\n/14/\n2019', '3/14/2019'], 'Job': ['Doctor', 'Cashier']}
```

However, this isn't addressing the fact that you end up with an empty string as a third name in your dictionary because the original csv has that ending comma. I fixed this by adding the following if statement.

```
import csv
myDict = {}
with open("members.txt") as file:
    for line in csv.reader(file):
        if line[-1] == "":
            myDict[line[0]] = line[1:-1]
        else:
            myDict[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

```
print(myDict)
{'Name': ['John', 'Susan'], 'Date': ['3\n/14/\n2019', '3/14/2019'], 'Job': ['Doctor', 'Cashier']}
```